# Why do SQLAlchemy query.all() and query.with_entities() return different data types?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Note: I'm using SQLAlchemy in Flask. The tables are ORM tables to an external database.

I have two queries which query data.

1. `CustomerTable.query.all()` and
2. `CustomerTable.query.with_entities(CustomerTable.id, CustomerTable.name, ...).all()`

Query 1 returns a list of objects of the class `CustomerTable`.
Query 2 returns a list of tuples containing the id, name, and all other columns

I can't figure out why that is the case. My problem with this behavior is that I can't access the data from Query 1 the same way as from Query 2.

What am I missing, or what am I doing wrong here?

I tried finding ways to convert the records from one "format" to another, but even if I succeed with this, I still don't understand what is causing this problem.

Comment: You told it to return just selected columns, not entire objects. So what class should they be in?

Answer (score 0):

The difference you're observing in the output of your two queries is related to how SQLAlchemy handles queries and the data it retrieves. Let's break down what's happening:

1. **`CustomerTable.query.all()`**:

   This query returns a list of objects, each representing a row in the database table. The objects are instances of the `CustomerTable` class, and you can access their attributes directly. For example:

   ```py
   customers = CustomerTable.query.all()

   for customer in customers:
       print(customer.id, customer.name)
   ```

   Each `customer` is an instance of the `CustomerTable` class, and you access its attributes using dot notation (`customer.id`, `customer.name`, etc.).
2. **`CustomerTable.query.with_entities(...).all()`**:

   This query returns a list of tuples. The `with_entities` method allows you to specify which columns you want in the result. In this case, you've specified `CustomerTable.id`, `CustomerTable.name`, and other columns. So, the result is a list of tuples where each tuple corresponds to a row in the database table.

   ```py
   customer_data = CustomerTable.query.with_entities(CustomerTable.id, CustomerTable.name).all()

   for data in customer_data:
       print(data[0], data[1])
   ```

   Here, `data` is a tuple, and you access its elements using indexing (`data[0]`, `data[1]`, etc.).

Comment: Thank you very much. This clears up a lot of confusion I had about how these two results come to be. However now, I'm struggling with the fact, that I have to find a way to somehow query both a specified selection of columns, and also all columns, and have the result be processed in the same way.

Meaning: is there a way to either get Objects from both queries, or Tuples from both queries, or somehow convert Query 1 or 2 into the format of the other one?